# "Convertible SqlValue UTCTime" missing?

Tags: haskell, hdbc

I was trying to convert a `SqlValue` into `UTCTime` like this:

```
import Database.HDBC
import Data.Time (UTCTime)

getUTCTimeFromSql :: SqlValue -> UTCTime
getUTCTimeFromSql time = fromSql time :: UTCTime
```

But GHC complains that I'm missing a `Convertible` instance to do this:

```
No instance for (Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible
                   SqlValue UTCTime)
  arising from a use of `fromSql'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible SqlValue UTCTime)
In the expression: fromSql time :: UTCTime
In an equation for `getUTCTimeFromSql':
    getUTCTimeFromSql time = fromSql time :: UTCTime
```

When I look at the [HDBC source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC/2.3.1.2/doc/html/src/Database-HDBC-SqlValue.html#SqlValue), the instance for `UTCTime` is there.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I could successfully load the snippet to GHCi (7.4.2) with HDBC-2.3.1.2 and convertible-1.0.11.1. What versions do you use?

Comment: I suspect that your `HDBC` (and `convertible`) were built against a different version of `time` than you are using. So there's an instance for the `UTCTime` of the older `time` package, but not for the type from the newer. Does `ghc-pkg list time` report more than one installed version?

Comment: Daniel, yes, indeed that was the reason. I had two versions of time registered so I removed one, re-installed some packages and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Daniel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353725/convertible-sqlvalue-utctime-missing#comment21702250_15353725) for the answer.

> I suspect that your HDBC (and convertible) were built against a
>   different version of time than you are using. So there's an instance
>   for the UTCTime of the older time package, but not for the type from
>   the newer. Does ghc-pkg list time report more than one installed
>   version?